# Does making use of int, long int, unsigned int have any significant difference on the execution time of a code?

Tags: c++

I was going through a problem on hackerearth which involved large numbers( >10<sup>4</sup>) and loop . I typed my code using `int` data type and executed it but for some test cases I had a time limited exceeded error.
Some people suggested to make use of long int instead of int.
Does it really make a difference?

Comment: If you exceed the time limit, I assume that replacing `int` with `unsigned` or `long` won't solve your issue (may be, accidentally but not reliably). Concerning the run-time of a code, it's usually the chosen algorithm which counts.

Comment: Depends on what the results will be.  If they are larger than what an `int` can hold then of course it will make a difference.  You'd have to post a problem statement and a [mcve] for us to be able to tell you if this is really the case for your code.

Comment: *"Does it really make a difference?"* It depends on your code. Please show it. Also, please avoid double tagging (use only C *or* C++ tag). Please [edit] your question and make these corrections.

Comment: The problem statement was to find total number of common divisors between 2 numbers where the numbers could be greater than 10^4

Comment: Note that on Windows (msvc), `int` and `long` are both 32bit integers.

Comment: If it would make a difference then it probably means your code is bugged. A profiler can help you pinpoint a performance hitch, and there's many debug tools out there to detect things like integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what architecture you use. For example

```
int64_t foo64(int64_t a, int64_t b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

on ARM Cortex (32 bit uC)

```
foo64:
        adds    r0, r0, r2
        adc     r1, r1, r3
        bx      lr
```

and on AVR (8 bit)

```
foo64:
        push r10
        push r11
        push r12
        push r13
        push r14
        push r15
        push r16
        push r17
        add r10,r18
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r10,r18
        brlo .L5
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L5:
        add r11,r19
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r11,r19
        brlo .L6
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L6:
        mov r19,r30
        add r19,r11
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r19,r11
        brlo .L7
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L7:
        or r18,r30
        add r12,r20
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r12,r20
        brlo .L8
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L8:
        mov r20,r18
        add r20,r12
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r20,r12
        brlo .L9
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L9:
        or r30,r18
        add r13,r21
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r13,r21
        brlo .L10
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L10:
        mov r21,r30
        add r21,r13
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r21,r13
        brlo .L11
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L11:
        or r18,r30
        add r14,r22
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r14,r22
        brlo .L12
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L12:
        mov r22,r18
        add r22,r14
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r22,r14
        brlo .L13
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L13:
        or r30,r18
        add r15,r23
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r15,r23
        brlo .L14
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L14:
        mov r23,r30
        add r23,r15
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r23,r15
        brlo .L15
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L15:
        or r18,r30
        add r16,r24
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        cp r16,r24
        brlo .L16
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L16:
        mov r24,r18
        add r24,r16
        ldi r18,lo8(1)
        cp r24,r16
        brlo .L17
        ldi r18,lo8(0)
.L17:
        or r30,r18
        add r25,r17
        mov r18,r10
        add r25,r30
        pop r17
        pop r16
        pop r15
        pop r14
        pop r13
        pop r12
        pop r11
        pop r10
        ret
```

more examples here: https://godbolt.org/z/agte93